# Accounting question about recording debits & credits

Tags: accounting

Please consider this simple spreadsheet, which tracks a $1,000 loan that I gave to a friend, along with the friend's payments against that initial loan.

```
type      date         amount
------------------------------
DEBIT     April 1st    -$1000
CREDIT    May 15th      +$200
CREDIT    June 15th     +$100
------------------------------
My account balance:     -$700
```

What is the formal accounting term to describe this?  Is it a balance sheet?  A ledger?  Something else?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This would be a simple ledger. A balance sheet is a summary and doesn't show individual transactions